# Strange timing issues in PyGame when animating bouncing balls

Tags: python, pygame

I am programming a game in PyGame and believe the code to be consistent for all the bouncing balls. However, after a while the balls bounce at different velocities.

Is my code erroneous? If so please could you try to identify where? If not, what is happening?

Thanks

My Code:

```
"""The IMPOSIBLE GAME"""

#Library
import time
import random
import pygame
import sys
from pygame.locals import *

Cube_x = 1
Cube_y = 1
Cube_x_vel = 0
Cube_y_vel = 0

#Colour Bank
Black = (0,0,0)
White = (255,255,255)
Red = (255,0,0)
Green = (0,255,0)
Blue = (0,0,255)
Dark_Purple = (102,0,102)
Orange = (255,128,0)

#Colour List
colour_list = [Black, White, Red, Blue, Green]

#Controls
UP = 'up'
DOWN = 'down'
LEFT = 'left'
RIGHT = 'right'

#Player Variables
DEATHS = 0
LEVEL = 1
SCORE = LEVEL - 1

#Sphere Coordinates
y_s1 = 0
y_s2 = 0
y_s3 = 0
y_s4 = 0
y_s5 = 0
sphere_vel = 5

#Shapes
def draw_CUBE(screen, colour, Cube_x, Cube_y):
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, colour, [Cube_x, Cube_y, 30, 30] ,0)

def draw_SPHERE1(Screen, y_s1):
    pygame.draw.ellipse(screen, Blue, [100, y_s1, 30, 30] ,0)

def draw_SPHERE2(Screen, y_s2):
    pygame.draw.ellipse(screen, Blue, [200, y_s2, 30, 30] ,0)

def draw_SPHERE3(Screen, y_s3):
    pygame.draw.ellipse(screen, Blue, [300, y_s3, 30, 30] ,0)

def draw_SPHERE4(Screen, y_s4):
    pygame.draw.ellipse(screen, Blue, [400, y_s4, 30, 30] ,0)

def draw_SPHERE5(Screen, y_s5):
    pygame.draw.ellipse(screen, Blue, [500, y_s5, 30, 30] ,0)


pygame.init()

#Window Variables
Cell_Size = 20
screen_width = 700
screen_height = 400
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

done = False

while not done:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    Cube_y_vel = -3
                    print("up")
                if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    Cube_y_vel = 3
                    print("down")

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    Cube_y_vel = 0
                    print("Key Released")
                if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    Cube_y_vel = 0
                    print("Key Released")



        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    Cube_x_vel = 3
                    print("up")
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    Cube_x_vel = -3
                    print("down")

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    Cube_x_vel = 0
                    print("Key Released")
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    Cube_x_vel = 0
                    print("Key Released")


    Cube_y = Cube_y + Cube_y_vel
    Cube_x = Cube_x + Cube_x_vel

    y_s1 = y_s1 + sphere_vel
    if y_s1 > 370:
        sphere_vel = sphere_vel * -1
    if y_s1 < 0:
        sphere_vel = sphere_vel * -1

    y_s2 = y_s2 + sphere_vel
    if y_s2 > 370:
        sphere_vel = sphere_vel * -1
    if y_s2 < 0:
        sphere_vel = sphere_vel * -1

    y_s3 = y_s3 + sphere_vel
    if y_s3 > 370:
        sphere_vel = sphere_vel * -1
    if y_s3 < 0:
        sphere_vel = sphere_vel * -1

    y_s4 = y_s4 + sphere_vel
    if y_s4 > 370:
        sphere_vel = sphere_vel * -1
    if y_s4 < 0:
        sphere_vel = sphere_vel * -1

    y_s5 = y_s5 + sphere_vel
    if y_s5 > 370:
        sphere_vel = sphere_vel * -1
    if y_s5 < 0:
        sphere_vel = sphere_vel * -1
    screen.fill((255,255,255))

    colour = random.choice(colour_list)

    draw_CUBE(screen, colour, Cube_x, Cube_y)

    draw_SPHERE1(screen, y_s1)

    draw_SPHERE2(screen, y_s2)

    draw_SPHERE3(screen, y_s3)

    draw_SPHERE4(screen, y_s4)

    draw_SPHERE5(screen, y_s5)

    pygame.draw.rect(screen, Green, [90, 400, 100, 100] , 0)

    pygame.display.flip()

    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at what happens here when `y_s1` becomes > `370`:

```
y_s1 = y_s1 + sphere_vel          # 1
if y_s1 > 370:
    sphere_vel = sphere_vel * -1  # 2
if y_s1 < 0:
    sphere_vel = sphere_vel * -1

y_s2 = y_s2 + sphere_vel          # 3
if y_s2 > 370:
    sphere_vel = sphere_vel * -1
if y_s2 < 0:
    sphere_vel = sphere_vel * -1  # 4
```

When `y_s1` becomes `375` (#1), you change `sphere_vel` from `5` to `-5` (#2), so in line #3 changes `y_y2` from `370` to `365`.

So now `y_s1` is always 10 apart from `y_s2`, `ys_3`, `ys_4` and `ys_5`.

The circles move down, and `y_s2` becomes `-5` at some time (since it is `10` smaller than `y_s1`).

So line #4 changes the sign of `sphere_vel` again, and `y_s3`, `ys_4` and `ys_5` therefore changes from `0` to `5`.

Now only `y_s2` is off by `10`, and that is what you see.

---

I suggest that you use pygame's `Sprite` and `Rect` class to make your life simpler.

Here's a simple example, note the comments:

```
# The IMPOSIBLE GAME

import random
import pygame
from pygame.color import Color
from pygame.surface import Surface
from pygame.sprite import Sprite, Group

pygame.init()

# note how pygame defines a lot of colors already for you
colour_list = [Color('Black'), Color('White'), Color('Red'), Color('Blue'), Color('Green')]

# we use a dict to keep a simple 'What Key Moves In Which Direction'-map
keys = {pygame.K_UP:    ( 0, -3),
        pygame.K_DOWN:  ( 0,  3),
        pygame.K_LEFT:  (-3,  0),
        pygame.K_RIGHT: ( 3,  0)}

# using sprites will make your live easy
# e.g. you don't need to handle drawing yourself
class Player(Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        Sprite.__init__(self)

        # we create a simple rectangular surface
        self.image = Surface((30, 30))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.image.fill(Color('Black'))

        # we set a colorkey so we can create a mask
        # this mask is used for pixel perfect collision
        # which will come in handy not only for circles
        # but if you extend your game to other shape
        self.image.set_colorkey(Color('Purple'))
        self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.image)
        self.deaths = 0

    def update(self):
        # use a random color from the list
        self.image.fill(random.choice(colour_list))

        # check which keys are pressed
        pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        for key, movement in keys.iteritems():
            if pressed[key]:
                # and move our rect in that direction
                # note how we don't need extra variables
                # the rect is enough
                self.rect.move_ip(movement)

        # we use the clamp_ip function to ensure your rect 
        # does not get out of screeen.
        self.rect.clamp_ip(pygame.display.get_surface().get_rect())

        # check if we collide with any object in the objects group
        # we use pygame.sprite.collide_mask to have a pixel perfect
        # collision detection
        # objects is a global variable, which may bother, but we could
        # simply pass it through the update function instead
        if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, objects, False, pygame.sprite.collide_mask):
            self.deaths += 1
            self.rect.topleft = (0, 0)

class Circle(Sprite):
    def __init__(self, start_x, speed):
        Sprite.__init__(self)
        # same as the in the Player class
        # we create a simple Surface
        self.image = Surface((30, 30))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(x=start_x, y=100)
        self.image.fill(Color('Purple'))
        self.image.set_colorkey(Color('Purple'))
        pygame.draw.ellipse(self.image, Color('Blue'), (0, 0, 30, 30), 0)
        self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.image)
        self.y_vel = speed

    def update(self):
        # we create a rect which will tell us
        # were we would move
        target = self.rect.move(0, self.y_vel)

        # and if we would go out of screen
        if not pygame.display.get_surface().get_rect().contains(target):
            # we simply change direction
            self.y_vel *= -1

        # then acutally move
        self.rect.move_ip(0, self.y_vel)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((700, 400))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
done = False

# When creating the circles, we can specify the start position and speed
objects = Group((Circle(x+100, 5) for x in xrange(0, 500, 100)))

# use a Group to handle updating and drawing
all_group = Group(*objects)
all_group.add(Player())

# your main loop is as easy as this
while not done:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

    all_group.update()

    screen.fill(Color('White'))
    all_group.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()

    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```

[image]

Comment: An excellent answer, fully explained and detailed example. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this seems to be due to two things. First because you move the balls before you check whether they are still on screen, and because your code creates some timing problems.

I would fix this by checking before moving the balls, and drawing the balls all at once in a for loop.

Example:

```
#Sphere Coordinates
ylist = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
sphere_vel = 5

#Shapes
def draw_SPHERE(Screen, x, y):
    pygame.draw.ellipse(screen, Blue, [x, y, 30, 30] ,0)

pygame.init()

done = False

while not done:

    screen.fill((255,255,255))
    for y in range(len(ylist)):
        if ylist[y] + sphere_vel > 370 or ylist[y] + sphere_vel < 0:
            sphere_vel = sphere_vel * -1
        ylist[y] = ylist[y] + sphere_vel
        draw_SPHERE(screen, (y+1) * 100, ylist[y])

    pygame.display.flip()

    clock.tick(60)
```